# determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix $a_{ij} = a^{|i-j|}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have a $n \times n$ matrix $a_{ij} = a^{|i-j|}$ which looks like this:

$$A=\pmatrix{1&a&a^2&\cdots&a^{n-1}\\
a&1&a&\cdots&a^{n-2}\\
a^2&a&1&\cdots&a^{n-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a^{n-1}&a^{n-2}&a^{n-3}&\cdots&1}$$

Computing the first few determinants yields:

$\det(A_1)=1$

$\det(A_2)=1-a^2$

$\det(A_3)=a^4-2a^2+1$

$\det(A_4)=-a^6+3a^4-3a^2+1$

Is there a pattern?

Comment: $(1-a^2)^{n-1}$

Comment: Observe that the coefficients of the determinant polynomial are entries in Pascal's triangle. You can prove the formula for $det(A_n)$  by induction.

Comment: I think this has been asked before, but I cannot locate the duplicate.